# How to delete background image in night mode theme?

Tags: android

My app has some activities. A number of these activities have a background image. and some activities do not. I want to add a night mode to the app. For this reason, I want to delete the background images in night mode but the day mode uses background images. How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When app in night mode you can remove background programmatic

```
if(isNightMode)yourLayout.setBackgroundResource(0);
else yourLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_image)
```